# Can't get morgan logger to only print failed requests

Tags: node.js, logging, express

I'm trying to get morgan logger to only print failed requests. The docs (https://www.npmjs.org/package/morgan) say to do this:

```
// EXAMPLE: only log error responses
morgan('combined', {
    skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
})
```

So here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('combined', {
    skip: function(req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
}));
```

However, every request just prints out "combined", and nothing else. Am I misunderstanding their example? I don't really see what else I should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
morganOptions = {
    skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400; }
};
```

Then, use morgan:

```
app.use(morgan('dev', morganOptions));
```

Answer (score 1):

Every request printed out "combined" for me too.

I updated morgan to the newest version, and it fixed the issue for me.
I guess the older versions don't support "combined" format

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the same problem.

It looks like the example is out of date.  Instead of `'combined'` try `'default'`.  You can see other valid options in the index.js file in the node_modules/morgan/index.js.

Comment: I gave 'default' a try, and now it's printing out responses like it should. But it isn't skipping successful responses, any ideas?